# Java enum switch

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have a simple enum

```
public enum Columns {VENDOR, ITEM};
```

That I am trying to extract and drive a switch code block.
What I am getting `classNotFound` for what appears to be the inner class for the enum, b/c it shows `[class]_A$0`. I thought enum was a static final and created object that I could use directly in the switch. Can someone clarify?

```
      colObject="VENDOR";
      for (Columns c : Columns.values()) {
        if (colObject.toUpperCase().equals(c.name())) {
          System.out.println("Got it in iteration. i= " + i + " c= " +
                             c);
          switch (c.valueOf(colObject.toUpperCase())) {
            case VENDOR: {
              System.out.println("Got it in switch case= " + c.name());
            }
            break;
            default:
              System.out.println("Fell thru.");
              break;
          }//end switch
        }//end if
      }//end for
```

Comment: Works for me (output is `"Got it in switch case= VENDOR"`) - no compile time or runtime errors. Can you provide a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) which reproduces the issue, and some additional information on the JDK version you are using?

Comment: Yes, your code as shown works (though you do need to fix that static access from a non-static context). Include the full stack trace and an SSCCE as suggested by Andreas.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
switch (Columns.valueOf(colObject.toUpperCase())) {
```

Comment: While it is true that calling a static method (`valueOf()`) on an object rather than on the class is bad practice, it technically does not make a difference. Both variants worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  `java.lang.Enum` class. `Enum` class will help to convert your `String "VENDOR"` to `enum-VENDOR`

Need to add following line of code

> Enum.valueOf(Columns.class, colObject))

`java.lang.Enum` can be used polymorphically whereas **Columns**(`enum`) cannot be used polymorphically.

**Complete code**

```
enum Columns {
    VENDOR, ITEM
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String colObject = "VENDOR";

        switch (Enum.valueOf(Columns.class, colObject)) 
        {
            case VENDOR: {
                System.out.println("Got it in switch case= VENDOR");
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Fell thru.");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```